# Android - Access PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS permission programmatically

Tags: android, android-permissions

There's no permission in `Manifest` class for the `android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS` permission. I need it for runtime asking for permissions.

Comment: there is no permission   like this in android `android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS` we have only `PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS` permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There's no permission in Manifest class for the android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS permission.

That is because Android does not have such a permission, as you can tell by looking at [Android's own manifest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml) and looking at the various `<permission>` elements.